# Bash shell string concatenation

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'm trying to create a string and pass it to `rm`, but I'm having some difficulty making it work.  I would like to remove everything in `MY_PATH`.  Below is what I've attempted.

```
MY_PATH=/my/directory/
echo ${MY_PATH}'*' # This works as expected.
rm -vfr ${MY_PATH}'*' # This doesn't.
```

EDIT: I figured it out.  I had a typo.

Comment: Never underestimate the importance of using double quotes. However you really don't need the braces to set a variable. Just having `rm -vfr "$MY_PATH"` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `echo` does *not* work properly. The shell is responsible for expanding wildcards, not rm.

```
rm -vfr "${MY_PATH}"*
```

Comment: or, better, use `rm -vfr "${MY_PATH}"/*`, in case the trailing `/` is forgotten when `MY_PATH` is set. As currently written, the difference between `MY_PATH=/my/dir/` and `MY_PATH=/my/dir` is that the latter will not only delete `/my/dir` (the directory, not just the contents), but will also delete `/my/dir1`, `/my/directory123`, `/my/directors_important_files` ...  And, best of all, check to verify that `MY_PATH` is actually set -- otherwise (with my suggested change) you'd try to (but probably fail, unless you're root) to delete everything under `/*`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the quotes, just use:
`rm -vrf ${MY_PATH}*`

Comment: Unless `$MY_PATH` contains whitespace.